# Tiled alternative to 9Patch?

Tags: android, nine-patch

I'm a designer/developer learning Android after a year spent developing on iOS.

iOS's equivalent of NinePatch/9patch is called resizableImageWithCapInsets. It allows the developer to take a regular PNG and programmatically specify the 9patch information -- that is, the info that goes in the 1-pixel border around a .9.png file for Android.

But with one key difference. On Android, the bits in the middle of the 9patch are *scaled*, whereas on iOS they're *tiled*. For some types of images this doesn't matter; but for anything with a texture or pattern scaling destroys the image.

Specifying the regions programmatically also allows designers use of tools like http://macrabbit.com/slicy that split a complex, master Photoshop files into individual image assets; as far as I can tell there aren't currently equivalent tools for Android 9patches. (The draw9patch tool that comes with the SDK doesn't work because you'd have to reuse it every time you exported from the main Photoshop file.)

I'm guessing one could create a Drawable subclass that mimics the iOS behavior: you pass it a plain old PNG and a set of 9patch dimensions and it draws itself appropriately, tiling the middle sections. You could even provide a switch to toggle between tile and stretch (which I wish iOS did).

As a newbie it'd take me some time to figure out how to do this. Does something like it already exist as an open source component or sample?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of an existing component for this. OTOH, Android's name for it is way cooler... :-) Note that `BitmapDrawable` (`<bitmap>` resources) know how to tile when applied as a background, but they do not have the notion of only tiling some subset of the area. If you wanted to roll your own, though, you might start there.

Comment: `On Android, the bits in the middle of the 9patch are scaled` - This is **false**. The bits which are scaled are the ones defined by the black areas (or single pixels) on the upper and the left borders. All the rest is not scaled (nor tiled).